# Processing window turns white (momentarily) on ellipse collision

Tags: processing

I have this odd instance where a grid of ellipses all collapse in to each other and create a sort of explosive collision, which is an interesting effect, but not desired.I really just want a smooth transition of smaller ellipses growing larger as they closer themselves to the center of the screen and then slowly transitioning over one other than creating a "explosion". I don't know where to start on why this might be occurring. Any suggestions?

I tried to take a screenshot, but capturing the explosion is quite difficult. Basically if you can imagine all 8 ellipses coming into one center point and then growing rapidly, thus making the rest of the window blip white.

[image: Ellipse Explosion]

```java
ArrayList<RotatingEllipse> ellipses = new ArrayList<RotatingEllipse>();

float updateSize = 1;
float minSize = 1;
float maxSize = 10;
float sizeSpeed = 0.015;



void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  noStroke();
  smooth();

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.25));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height*.75));
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height*.75));

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2, height*.25)); 
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width/2, height*.75)); 

  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.25, height/2)); 
  ellipses.add(new RotatingEllipse(width*.75, height/2));
}

void draw() {
  background(#202020);


  for (RotatingEllipse e : ellipses) {
    e.stepAndDraw();

    updateSize = map(sin(frameCount * sizeSpeed), -1.0, 1.0, minSize, maxSize);

  }
}

class RotatingEllipse {

  float rotateAroundX;
  float rotateAroundY;
  float distanceFromRotatingPoint;
  float angle;

  public RotatingEllipse(float startX, float startY) {

    rotateAroundX = (width/2 + startX)/2;
    rotateAroundY = (height/2 + startY)/2;

    distanceFromRotatingPoint = dist(startX, startY, rotateAroundX, rotateAroundY);

    angle = atan2(startY-height/2, startX-width/2);
  }

  public void stepAndDraw() {

    angle += PI/128;

    float x = rotateAroundX + cos(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;
    float y = rotateAroundY + sin(angle)*distanceFromRotatingPoint;

    float distance = dist(x, y, width/2, height/2);
    float diameter = 50*(200-distance)/500;
    float m = map ( updateSize, 0, distance, 1, diameter);

    ellipse(x, y, m, m);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the values of `m` you're using:

```
float m = map ( updateSize, 0, distance, 1, diameter);
println(m);
ellipse(x, y, m, m);
```

If you print `m` out, you'll see something like this:

```
60.552975
85.61453
85.42698
85.440994
85.46013
120.79626
120.83713
120.847946
120.81186
4292781.0
4282823.5
611831.94
234653.25
1730522.2
448653.88
336490.44
2018942.4
85.23538
85.03087
85.0165
84.99791
120.24554
120.20372
120.19415
120.23001
42.533062
```

You are making your ellipses **HUGE**, which fills up the screen, which is why the whole screen turns white.

You need to refactor your code to eliminate these huge values. I don't really understand what you're trying to do with the `updateSize` and the `map()` function, which seems overly complicated. But you're going to have to modify that code so it doesn't generate such large values.

You could also just cap the value using an if statement, but I think the real answer is to simplify your logic for changing the size.

Comment: Originally, I didn't have an updateSize and the size grew in relation to the distance of each ellipses own center point. However, That caused variation in sizes on each diagonal ellipse from the center of the screen. Therefore, I thought back to the original code that relied on the center o the screen to create the ellipse size. I will rethink the code. Thanks